# Как рисовать в Chart  в отдельном потоке?

Tags: c#

Как рисовать в Chart  в отдельном потоке?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/133130/c-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-chart-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

У Чарта есть метод Invoke, юзай его